# UDP packets rejected at OS-level?

Tags: networking, udp, ip

Running on a Linux system, getting UDP packets from another computer address to let's say 192.168.0.2 from another address let's say 192.168.166.66, I can see the UDP packets coming in with tcpdump.  However, if I use netcat I don't actually receive the packets.

If I create an interface on 192.168.166.XXX network, then netcat is able to receive the packets no problem.

What basic networking concept am I missing?  Why do I need to have an interface on the network of the sending IP when I can see with tcpdump that they are being delivered correctly?

Comment: Do both the source and destination hosts have correct routing for each other? I assume `0.2` knows how to route to `166.66`, given you said you can see the packets coming in; are you sure the return traffic is being properly routed to `0.2`? Does simple ping traffic between the hosts work as intended?

Comment: admdrew, pings don't work because the receiver (192.168.0.2) does not have an interface on the 192.168.166.XXX network.  But with tcpdump I can verify that the packets are getting to the interface, just being dropped at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution to this problem was to disable Reverse Path Forwarding (RPF) on the interface.  There are security implications here, but after careful review this was the correct path forward in this particular case.

RPF was turned off by modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
```

Some more information on RPF:

[Wikipedia - Reverse path forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_path_forwarding)

[Linux kernel rp_filter settings](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-kernel-rpfilter-settings-reverse-path-filtering)

Answer (score 2):

tcpdump per default puts the interface into promiscious mode, which lets you see all the packets arriving at your network interface.  But, your operating system only processes packets destined for the local system, e.g. either having the local or a broadcast address as destination.

Comment: The UDP traffic is 192.168.166.66 --> 192.168.0.2.

192.168.0.2 is the address of the receiving machine, so why do the packets get rejected at the OS level?

Comment: From your initial description I assumed that they get rejected because 192.168.0.2 wasn't your local address. With the new but still very few details about your network setup I would assume the there is no route back to the sender so they get rejected. Maybe you should post output from ifconfig -a and netstat -rn so that one can actually see how your network is set up

Comment: So if I set up a route back to 192.168.166.66 I'd be able to receive them from that address?  I didn't think you would need that for UDP to work.  Is that the basic networking concept I'm missing?

Comment: Packets get typically rejected by the OS if there is no route back for a reply. More secure systems will also check, that the outgoing route will be on the same interface where the packet came in.